# Boost - CMake doesn't find lib

Tags: boost, cmake

I try to link Boost libraries in my CMakeList on Windows. Here is my code :

```
set(BOOST_ROOT C:/lib/boost_1_59_0)
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR C:/lib/boost_1_59_0/lib)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system REQUIRED)
if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

My folder "lib" contains all the lib build by bjam, including "libboost_system-vc140-mt-1_59.lib" and "libboost_system-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib".

It works for headers, but It doesn't find libs. I have this error :

```
Error:Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.
Boost version: 1.59.0
Boost include path: C:/lib/boost_1_59_0
Could not find the following Boost libraries:
    boost_system
No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the    directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of Boost.
```

I try a lot of things (this is the first time I ask a question here, I really search a lot before asking) like "add_definitions(-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB)" or change the path to "C:\lib\boost_1_59_0" but I find nothing to fix it.

If anyone have an idea, I will thank him a lot !

Comment: Run with `Boost_DEBUG` variable set to non-zero. It should be some additional messages from Boost in the build log. Also setting `Boost_DETAILED_FAILURE_MSG` variable could be usefull.

Comment: I was searching for "Boost_DEBUG" and I find my answer, so thanks ! I forgot to tell bjam that I use mingw.

Answer (score 0):

**CMake Configuration- Boost- Visual Studio - C++**

Step 1: Download CMake installation file, install and save it in local disk

Step 2: Create 2 Folders in local disk a) Raw File   b)Solution File

Step 3: Raw File folder- Create a Main.cpp file and paste your raw c++ code it it and save. Now in the same folder create a txt file named CMakeLists and paste the following code in it and save.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project (cmboosttest)
#find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
#include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_executable(boosttest ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Main.cpp)
```

Step 4: Open CMake choose Raw File folder in browse source and Solution File Folder in browse build.

Step 5: Click Configure. Once it succeeds, click Generate.

Step 6: When you open the Solution File folder, you can see the built solution file. Click on it and your program will open in Visual Studio. Now, build your program in VS.

Hope this helps!